# Why aren't new versions of module showing up in CPAN?

Tags: perl, cpan

So I'm trying to install `Pod::ProjectDocs` and it requires `Syntax::Highlight::Universal`. `P/PA/PALANT/Syntax-Highlight-Universal-0.4.tar.gz` from CPAN fails to build on my machine for some reason, but I downloaded `M/MI/MISHOO/Syntax-Highlight-Universal-0.5.tar.gz` and it builds fine with a perl Makefile.PL && make && make test && make install.

Version 0.4 was added to cpan in 2005 and 0.5 in 2009.

So, question: Even though the newer version (by a different author?) has been in CPAN for a while, why isn't it showing up when I search for it? It's not being mirrored by `CPAN::Mini` either apparently because it's not in `02packages.details.txt`, but who decides what goes in there?

```
cpan[4]> i /syntax::highlight::universal/          
Module id = Syntax::Highlight::Universal
    DESCRIPTION  Syntax highlighter based on Colorer library
    CPAN_USERID  MISHOO (Mihai Bazon <mihai.bazon@gmail.com>)
    CPAN_VERSION 0.4
    CPAN_FILE    P/PA/PALANT/Syntax-Highlight-Universal-0.4.tar.gz
    UPLOAD_DATE  2005-03-13
    DSLIP_STATUS Rd+hp (released,developer,C++,hybrid,Standard-Perl)
    MANPAGE      Syntax::Highlight::Universal - Syntax highlighting module based on the Colorer library
    INST_FILE    /opt/perl/perl-5.12.2/lib/site_perl/5.12.2/i686-linux/Syntax/Highlight/Universal.pm
    INST_VERSION 0.5

cpan[5]> d /syntax-highlight-universal/  
Distribution id = P/PA/PALANT/Syntax-Highlight-Universal-0.4.tar.gz
    CPAN_USERID  PALANT (Wladimir Palant <palant@cpan.org>)
    CONTAINSMODS Syntax::Highlight::Universal
    UPLOAD_DATE  2005-03-13
```

Comment: This should probably be asked in a forum for supporting CPAN and Perl.  Maybe at PerlMonks.  I'd not be surprised to find that the trouble is that PALANT has dropped off the planet and MISHOO has not been formally given permission to take over S::H::U.  Certainly, MISHOO has been active as recently as 2010, but PALANT has the one distribution from 2005.

Comment: I also note that S::H::U 0.5 is not safe for 64-bit versions of Perl (and doesn't compile); it converts an address to `int`, which is not a good idea - I'd recommend `uintptr_t` though the code in question is C++ so that might not be a good idea.  And it takes more than just fixing the one variable's type; it is passed to a more general function, which needs to be fixed too...

Comment: I posted the question at perlmonks as well: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=886285 I was under the impression that CPAN was basically anarchy and anyone with an account could upload modules that could be installed via the cpan command, but apparently I was wrong...

Comment: If you're not listed as the maintainer (or co-maintainer) of a module on PAUSE, it won't let you upload new versions of that module.

Comment: @cespinoza, I wouldn't call it anarchy but yes, anyone with an account can upload whatever they please as long as the license is some variety of open source and the content isn't so radically offensive that 99% of Perl hackers would reject it. I would argue this permissiveness (low barrier to entry) is the root of CPAN's success.

Comment: @CanSpice, that is semi-correct. One can upload an "unauthorized" release. These packages won't be pulled down by most cpan tools by default but are available if intentionally chosen.

Comment: @ashley 'intentionally chosen' as in manually downloaded & built from a cpan mirror? Or can I somehow convince cpan/cpanp/etc to do it for me?

Comment: I highly recommend cpanm (App::cpanminus), this should do it- `cpanm http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/M/MI/MISHOO/Syntax-Highlight-Universal-0.5.tar.gz` -- sorry, if you want the earlier, do this - `cpanm http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/P/PA/PALANT/Syntax-Highlight-Universal-0.4.tar.gz`

Comment: Actually it seems that MISHOO is listed as a co-maintainer for that module. search.cpan.org shows him as the registrant for the Syntax::Highlight::Universal namespace. Did you send and e-mail to both authors?

Comment: I would guess that MISHOO uploaded 0.5 before becoming an authorized maintainer of Syntax::Highlight::Universal.  If that's the case, he just needs to use the [Force Reindexing tool at PAUSE](https://pause.perl.org/pause/authenquery?ACTION=reindex) to get the index updated.

Comment: @cespinoza: please in future, when cross-posting, it is considerate to add a note that you have done this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MISHOO probably uploaded 0.5 before becoming an authorized maintainer of Syntax::Highlight::Universal.

If that's the case, he just needs to use the Force Reindexing tool at PAUSE to get the index updated.

Note: This is cjm's comment (highest rated) copied as an answer so that the question is eventually removed from the unanswered page. I am setting this as community wiki so as not to take credit for his answer.